# Ansible show real-time log in different CLI tab

Tags: ansible

I have a command in ansible that runs `npm run dev` where dev basically runs `webpack -d --watch`. Webpack handles my sass files, and shows a real-time log output in my CLI window.

Now, when I run this command through ansible, it doesn't show the logs if I make any changes to my sass files. From what I understand, ansible does not show real-time logs while the command is running (correct me if I am wrong). But is there a way I can open a new tab in my Terminal that shows the logs in real-time?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is  modify your task to something like this:

```
- name: My command
  shell: webpack -d --watch 2>&1 > /some/log/file
```

And then track the `/some/log/file`

Comment: Thank you. Can I `less +F /the/log/file` in another terminal window or tab (OS-independently) through a bash command?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. `less +F` or `tail -f`, whatever you wish